# fork / pipe / close in a recursive function

Tags: c, unix, recursion, pipe, dup2

In order to realize a shell command interpretor, I try to execute pipes.
To do it, I use a recursive function in wich I use the pipe function and some redirections with dup2.
Here is my code :

```
void            test_recurs(pid_t pid, char **ae)
{
  char  *const  arg[2] = {"/bin/ls", NULL};
  char  *const  arg2[3] = {"/bin/wc", NULL};
  static int    limit = 0;
  int           check;
  int           fd[2];

  if (limit > 5)
    return ;
  if (pipe(fd) == -1)
    {
      printf("pipe failed\n");
      return ;
    }
  pid = fork();
  if(pid != 0)
    {
      printf("père %d\n",getpid());
      close(fd[0]);
      dup2(fd[1], 1);
      close(fd[1]);
      if ((execve("/bin/ls", arg, ae)) == -1)
        exit(125);
      dprintf(2, "execution ls\n");
      wait(&check);
    }
  else
    {
      printf("fils %d\n", getpid());
      close(fd[1]);
      dup2(fd[0], 0);
      close(fd[0]);
      if ((execve("/bin/wc", arg2, ae)) == -1)
        printf("echec execve\n");;
      dprintf(2, "limit[%d]\n", limit);
      limit++;
      test_recurs(pid, ae);
    }
}
```

The problem is it only execute "ls | wc" one time and then wait on the standard input. I know that the problem may come from the pipes (and the redirections).

Comment: `execve` will never return. (Well, ok, it will return if it didn't work.)

Comment: It returns -1 when it doesn't work yeah...

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear how you are trying to use the function you present, but here are some notable points about it:

- It's poor form to rely on a static variable to limit recursion depth because it's not thread-safe and because you need to do extra work to manage it (for example, to ensure that any changes are backed out when the function returns).  Use a function parameter instead.
- As has been observed in comments, the exec-family functions return only on failure.  Although you acknowledge that, I'm not sure you appreciate the consequences, for both branches of your fork contain code that will never be executed as a result.  The recursive call in particular is dead and will never be executed.
- Moreover, the process in which the function is called performs an `execve()` call itself.  The reason that function does not return is that it *replaces* the process image with that of the new process.  That means that function `test_recurs()` *also* does not return.

Just as shell ordinarily must fork / exec to launch a single external command, it ordinarily must fork / exec for *each* command in a pipeline.  If it fails to do so then afterward it is no longer running -- whatever it exec'ed without forking runs instead.

> The problem is it only execute "ls | wc" one time and then wait on the standard input.

Certainly it does not recurse, because the recursive call is in a section of dead code.  I suspect you are mistaken in your claim that it afterward waits on standard input, because the process that calls that function execs `/bin/ls`, which does not read from standard input.  When the `ls` exits, however, leaving you with neither shell nor `ls`, what you then see might seem to be a wait on stdin.